# How to publish generic file using web publish in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-web-roles

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (I am using VS for 10 years) and I publish a web site using web publish to Azure. I want to publish a generic file lets say a .dat file that users will download. How should I add it to project so that it is published and available to download by users. I tried adding to specific folder in project, setting build to content and always copy. I can see the folder created but when I type specific URL , i got generic file or folder not found error. If I put an xml file to same folder , I can see it with direct url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Information Service does not serve the files that it does not know about. Your `.dat` file is not supported by `IIS` by default so you have to add it manually.

Add following configuration to your `web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```